# How to apply the alternating series test to the series $\sum (-1)^{n+1} n/2^n$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So, I need to test the following series for convergence or divergence:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}{n\over {2^n}}$$

I know that when you use the Alternating Series Test, the series must satisfy two conditions. Which are:

1. $$b_{n+1} \le b_n $$
2. $$\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n =0$$

I having a hard time with the first condition because if I use 1  for n then I have a problem.
This is my work so far:

$$ {(n+1)\over 2^{(n+1)}} ? {n\over 2^n}$$
$$ {(1+1)\over 2^{(1+1)}} ? {1\over 2^1}$$
$$ {(2)\over 2^{(2)}} ? {1\over 2^1}$$
$$ {2\over 4} = {1\over 2}$$
They end up equaling each other.
On the other hand, if I plug in 2, I get something that does satisfy the first condition.$$ {(n+1)\over 2^{(n+1)}} ? {n\over 2^n}$$
$$ {(2+1)\over 2^{(2+1)}} ? {2\over 2^2}$$
$$ {(3)\over 2^{(3)}} ? {2\over 2^2}$$
$$ {3\over 8} ? {2\over 4}$$
$$ {3\over 8} \le {1\over 2}$$

So... what do I do?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not an alternating series, so the test does not apply. Use instead the comparison test. with $\sum{1\over\sqrt{2}^n}$

Comment: Do you mean $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n}{2^n}$?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Thanks I just fixed it. Sorry.

Comment: Don't worry specifically about the $n=1$ case. Try to prove it for all $n \geq 1$.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I am trying to get through Calc II and it isn't fun...and I have an exam on this stuff tomorrow.

Comment: This is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, it's pretty straightforward:

First note that $b_{n}\ge b_{n+1}\iff b_n-b_{n+1}\ge 0$, then consider the reformulated question:

> $$b_{n}-b_{n+1}={n+1\over 2^{n+1}}-{n\over 2^n}\stackrel{?}{\ge}0$$

this is true if and only if the same is true after multiplying both sides by $2^{n+1}$, because multiplying both sides of an inequality by a positive number keep the inequality true, so

$$2n-(n+1)=n-1\stackrel{?}{\ge}0$$

which is true so long as $n\ge 1$, so that checks out.

To see the limit goes to zero you can proceed either by using

> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}{x\over 2^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty} {1\over 2^x\ln 2}=0$$

using L'Hôpital's rule or by noting $n\le \sqrt{2}^n$ for every $n\ge 1$

This is the same as saying $n^2\le 2^n$ for every $n\ge 1$, which is verified by base case:  $n=1$, $1\le 2$ check. Assume it's true for some $n\ge 1$, then

$$(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1\le 2^n +2n+1\le 2^n+n^2 < 2^n+2^n=2^{n+1}$$

by inductive hypothesis, and since $2n+1\le n^2$ for $n\ge 1$, so the rest follows by induction, and we have

> $$0\le\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\over 2^n}\le\lim_{n\to\infty}{(\sqrt{2})^n\over 2^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over(\sqrt{2})^n}=0$$

which settles that by the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Sorry, but where did the n-1 come from?

Comment: $2n-(n+1) - 2n-n-1=n-1$

Comment: Oh okay thanks. I get it know!

Comment: Oh alright. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use induction. The first step is obvious. Assume $\frac{k}{2^k}>\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}}$. Then $\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{k}{2^{k}}+\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2^{k}}>\frac{1}{2}\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{k+2}{2^{k+2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

As corrected, this *is* an alternating series.

Also,
for the alternating series test
to be applied to
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n$,
all that is needed is that
$a_{n+1} < a_n$
for all $n > N$
for *some* $N$.
Any initial part of a series
is irrelevant when discussing convergence.

In this case,
the fact that
$\dfrac{n}{2^n}$
is eventually decreasing
has been discussed here
too many times.

Answer (score 0):

To check if $\dfrac{n}{2^n}$ is eventually decreasing, it suffices to show that the derivative of $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{x}{2^x}$ is eventually negative.

To do so, note that 
$$
f^\prime(x)=\frac{2^x-x\cdot 2^x\ln2}{2^{2x}}=\frac{1-x\cdot\ln{2}}{2^x}
$$
For $x>1/\ln2$ we have $f^\prime(x)<0$. Hence $\dfrac{n}{2^n}$ is eventually decreasing.